# Is it possible to find authors' agents?

Tags: agent

I am trying to locate agents in my area of writing, so as to better target the limited amount of queries I'm sending.  There are several other writers writing in similar genres/niches, and I would be interested in contacting their agents, who clearly have an affinity for this area of writing.  Short of directly tweeting/emailing these authors to ask for their agents (which strikes me as discourteous/unprofessional), is there a database of authors and their agents I could consult?

Answer (score 2):

Look at *The Complete Idiot's Guide to Finding a Literary Agent* (http://www.penguin.com/static/pages/cig/quickguides/literary-agent.php), it lists lists of agents.

Answer (score 1):

In most books, the author will have an acknowledgements page or two, and they almost always include the name of their agent. A few other helpful places to look:

1. Acknowledgements page in the back of the author's book
2. [aaronline.org](http://aaronline.org/) (AAR is an association of agents that requires a certain level of ethics, e.g. no reading fees)
3. *Writers Digest's Guide to Literary Agents* and [Writers Market](http://www.writersmarket.com/)
4. Look for big conferences in your genre - they usually have visiting agents. (For example, I write thrillers, so I looked at the International Thriller Writers conference page where they listed agents coming to the conference.)
5. **BIG ONE** Look at [Publishers Marketplace](http://publishersmarketplace.com/). They have a listing of all agents, authors, book deals, etc. that are going on right now in the industry. It does cost a little, but it is definitely worth it.

Answer (score 0):

find a copy of

> 2015 Guide to Literary Agents - Sambuchino, Chuck

or

> 2015 Writer's Market - Robert Lee Brewer

Answer (score 0):

[AgentQuery.com](http://agentquery.com) has a searchable directory of agents that can be filtered by genre and/or keyword.